# How to organize database connections in larger Python/Flask applications?

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I am currently trying to write a little web-application using python, flask and sqlite and I'm not sure about how to handle the database-connections.

Basically I've been following the "official" Tutorial (and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlite3/#sqlite3 ), leaving me with code like this in my main Flask/App module (drastically shortened):

```
@vs_app.before_request
def before_request():
    g.db = sqlite3.connect("somedb.db")

def execute_db(command):
    return g.db.cursor().execute(command).fetchall()

@app.route("/givemeallusers")
def foo():
    return execute_db("SELECT * FROM users")
```

So this creates a DB-Connection for each request that can be used by my application to execute sql-commands and it works fine for smaller applications.
But for a larger project I'd like to put my database-code (with some utility methods) and app-code in different modules, so I could (for example) write:

```
from my_database_module import user_auth #

@app.route("/login")
def foo():
    if user_auth(request.form["name"], request.form["pw"]):
        pass
```

But for that I would need access to g (or g.db) from my database-class and the only way I could get that to work was by "manually" handing over the db-connection to each method, leaving me with code like this:

```
@app.route("/login")
def foo():
    if user_auth(g.db, request.form["name"], request.form["pw"]):
        pass
```

and in my database-module

```
def user_auth(database, name, pw):
    pass
```

I don't think thats the best approach, but other ideas I had (like importing the g object into my database-class) don't work. I also don't know whether my approach is safe with regards to concurrent db-access, so any help with this would be appreciated.
tl;dr How to split Flask-App and Database/Database-Utility the right way?

Comment: I suggest you look at Flask-SQlAlchemy http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/

Comment: Why not simply access the same `g.db` within your `user_auth` method, rather than passing it in? Since it is a thread local, everything *should* just work.

Comment: 1. I am currently looking into Flask-SQLAlchemy. Don't know what to think of it yet :)
2. I tried that by importing "g" from my database-module, but then again i'd need to import my auth-method into my main-module, which is not possible because of circular dependencies

Comment: You REALLy should follow the advice and use Flask-SQLAlchemy.

Comment: I've been rebuilding the application using Flask-SQLAlchemy. While it took me a bit to get it up and running (and I'll suppose it will take me even longer to get some N:M-Mapping correctly), I have to say I'm quite impressed by its usability so far, definitely worth the effort I would say. Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case someone stumbles upon this question:
The correct answer is to not bother with the approaches described in the Question, and instead just start working with Flask-SQLAlchemy.